# Is it true that a computer processor only knows how to sum?

Tags: cpu

I had a teacher 2 years ago who told me that computer processors only know how to add values. That you need to tell them how to substract, divide, and multiply by programming.

Comment: Closing as off-topic because you can easily get to this information by searching for it and this doesn't help you [solve any problem in a practical way in a Super User context](http://superuser.com/faq). As Ignacio shows, there is no single valid answer. Consult [Wikipedia - CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) and [Wikipedia - ALU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) for a better understanding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* create a CPU that only knows how to sum and then derives everything from that, but modern CPUs use additional operations such as shifts as well as tables for expensive operations such as division in order to run at high speed.